# Is it reasonable to say the integral of pdf of the standard normal is equal to 1? What is the process of derivation?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

These are basic rules of distribution

1. the total area beneath a probability density function equal to 1.0
2. the probability density function of the standard normal is equal  $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2} e^{- \frac{x^{2}}{2}}}{2 \sqrt{\pi}}$

Based on the facts above, is it reasonable to say the integral of pdf of the standard normal is equal to 1? What is the process of derivation?

I am trying to deduct the process. This code

```
phi = 1/sqrt(2*pi)*exp(-(x**2)/2)
integrate(phi, x)
```

outputs

$\displaystyle \frac{\operatorname{erf}{\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} x}{2} \right)}}{2}$

How can I get this result and connect it to rule_1?

The Gauss error function is defined as

${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}\operatorname {erf} (x)&={\frac {1}{\sqrt {\pi }}}\int _{-x}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}\,dt\\[5pt]&={\frac {2}{\sqrt {\pi }}}\int _{0}^{x}e^{-t^{2}}\,dt.\end{aligned}}}$

plugin $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2} x}{2}$

I got

${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}{\frac {2}{\sqrt {\pi }}}\int _{0}^{\frac{\sqrt{2} x}{2}}e^{-t^{2}}\,dt.\end{aligned}}}$

what is the next?

Comment: You want the definite integral over $\mathbb R$. So what are $\operatorname{erf}(x)$ and $\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} x}{2} \right)$ as $x \to +\infty$ and  $x \to -\infty$?  What do you get with half the difference?

Comment: @Henry Thanks for your guidance. I am making the progress! Does the "difference" in " half the difference" mean the value of $\operatorname{erf}(x)$?

Comment: If your aim is show $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{\pi}$ or something equivalent, then read about the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)